# python variable in the function call

Tags: python, string, function, datetime

i'm trying to create a directory/folder in linux using python. I will get date time and make a folder.

```
In [65]: d = datetime.datetime.now()

In [66]: a = 'date :' + str(d)

In [67]: a
Out[67]: 'date :2011-02-01 13:05:58.642704'

In [68]: os.system('mkdir a')
```

How should i pass the variable a in the system command??

Comment: You shouldn't. http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Comment: `os.system(' '.join(['mkdir', a])`

Comment: `os.system('mkdir {}'.format(a))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to name your directory `'date :2011-02-01 13:05:58.642704'` with all those colons and spaces? There is a simple way to format the date in a different form, that will make the string manipulation easier.

For example:

```
d = datetime.datetime.now()

a = d.strftime('date_%Y%m%d_%H%M%S_%f')
os.mkdir(a)
```

which will create a directory named `date_20110201_130558_642704` (more about the formatting options [here](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)). Your life will be easier if you manipulate this directory in the shell (double-clicking on its name in an `ls` output, etc.)

Comment: yea eumiro, i was looking something similar above!! its small task of backup and i don't know more of python, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Use string formatting to add the var `a` to the string:

```
os.system('mkdir %s' % a)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use python's own way of making directories:

```
os.mkdir(a)
```

Comment: but when i use this mkdir inside a function like os.system('').

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* use `os.system`. Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) if you have to call an external program.

That said, there is no reason to call `mkdir`. Use the stdlib function [os.mkdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkdir), that does what you want. Using the stdlib wherever possible is recommended. Not only will your code be portable, it will be easier to maintain and read also.

If you insist on calling an external process:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['mkdir', 'foo_bar'])
```